# Amazon AWS IOS SDK: How to list ALL file names in a FOLDER

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS IOS SDK and trying to list all the files in a FOLDER.

This code works to list all files etc in a BUCKET:

```
-(void) s3DirectoryListing: (NSString *) bucketName {

    s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];

    @try {

        S3ListObjectsRequest *req = [[S3ListObjectsRequest alloc] initWithName:bucketName];

        S3ListObjectsResponse *resp = [s3Client listObjects:req];

        NSMutableArray* objectSummaries = resp.listObjectsResult.objectSummaries;  

        for (int x = 0; x < [objectSummaries count]; x++) {
            NSLog(@"objectSummaries: %@",[objectSummaries objectAtIndex:x]);
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Cannot list S3 %@",exception);
}

}
```

So if I pass a bucketName name, this works.  However if I try and pass bucketName/folderName" I get an error message.  This code doesn't seem to like the combination of bucket and folder path combinations.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a "flat" file system, meaning it does not have physical folders. "Folders" as you know are simply prefixes added to file names.

You need to set the `prefix` property to your request (see the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/class_s3_list_objects_request.html))

For example, given the following set of files:

> folderName1/fileNameA.txt
>   folderName1/fileNameB.txt
>   folderName2/folderName3/fileNameC.txt

If you set `prefix` with `folderName1`, and your `delimiter` with `/`, you should get only the first two entries.

Last, but not least, leave your `bucketName` only with the bucket name :)

More info at the [S3 Developer Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html?r=6295).

Comment: Actually for this to work you have to set the prefix to "folderName1/". It wasn't so obvious to me before reading the doc that the prefix must include the delimiter in order to work...

Comment: Another thing to watch out for: The result set is truncated at 1000. Check the isTruncated flag and run consecutive requests with a marker for stating the last object obtained.