# AWS SDK public url for file in bucket

Tags: ios, sdk, amazon-web-services

I have referenced the answer below to retrieve all files in a bucket.

[Amazon AWS IOS SDK: How to list ALL file names in a FOLDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329234/amazon-aws-ios-sdk-how-to-list-all-file-names-in-a-folder)

Is there any way to retrieve the public url to retrieve download the file using the iOS AWS SDK?